# Can I configure AzerothCore so that WLK can be played from start to finish (raids) with only two people?

Tags: azerothcore, trinitycore

I've recently found [AzerothCore](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk) and I was wondering if it could be configured or modded so that I could play the entirety of WLK with a friend, from start to finish (raids).

Quite a lot of years ago (more than 8) I used [TrinityCore](https://github.com/TrinityCore/TrinityCore) to play some WLK raids with friends, but back then I basically had to manually create a buff that would increase HP and Damage, which while made the raid possible in 4-5 players, was really difficult to balance and either it trivialized the raid or didn't make them beatable anyway.

AzerothCore looks like it's one of the most up-to-date and developped WLK emulator and I saw there's a "mod" called "mod-autobalance" that seems to promise just what I need. Before start looking into fixing my Linux server (which is offline at the moment) I wanted to see if my idea to play the game from level 1 to killing the Lich King with a friend is feasible at all and if so, with what compromises.

Lastly, any kind of tip, guidance or advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use [mod-autobalance](https://github.com/azerothcore/mod-autobalance) for it. Start to play with your friends from 1 to 80 lvl, walk through the instances one by one according to your level and then you can kill the Lich King.

Comment: Thank you very much :-) I'm assuming one of us must be a tank, right?